# On Database Change: Code First mode with code generated from an EDMX file for either Database First

Tags: sql, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have two environments on different servers, development and test.

When I deploy my MVC site to both servers provided there both pointing to the development database everything works fine, As soon as i change the connection string to use the test servers database I receive the following error..

"The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development."

What would cause this issue? from my viewpoint the database is present on both servers and their tables etc are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Turned out that the connection string name had been changed, reverting this change has allowed the application to load without error.